# How to setup Django, mod_wsgi and apache on Mac OSX Lion?

Tags: django, macos, apache, mod-wsgi

I am having trouble setting Django with Apache on Mac OSX Lion (10.7.2). I created a Django project as per the tutorial and can run it on the development server. Now I want to run it locally on my Mac with Apache. I created the two files indicated below.

apache_django_wsgi.conf

```
WSGIDaemonProcess django
WSGIProcessGroup django

Alias /site_media/ "/Users/David/Dropbox/sites/walble/media/"
<Directory "/Users/David/Dropbox/sites/walble/media">
Order allow,deny
Options Indexes
Allow from all
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

Alias /media/ "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/"
<Directory "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media">
Order allow,deny
Options Indexes
Allow from all
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /walble "/Users/David/Dropbox/sites/walble/apache/walble.wsgi"

<Directory "/Users/David/Dropbox/sites/walble/apache">
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

walble.wsgi

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/Users/David/Dropbox/sites/walble')
sys.path.append('/Users/David/Dropbox/sites')

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'walble.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

In `httpd.conf`, I enabled 
`LoadModule wsgi_module libexec/apache2/mod_wsgi.so` and then added the following line.

`Include /Users/David/Dropbox/sites/walble/apache/apache_django_wsgi.conf`

I restarted Apache and then in the browser I typed in `http://localhost/walble` but I get a forbidden message like so

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /walble on this server.

Apache/2.2.20 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.1 PHP/5.3.6 with Suhosin-Patch Server at localhost Port 80
```

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common permissions problem. The Apache user does not have execute permissions on the `walble.wsgi` file.

Comment: How do I give Apache permissions to this file?

Comment: Go watch the presentation http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6#Conference_Presentations which explains this error and how to setup permissions.